# Add new product to the category with position 0 instead of last for Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category

I've been trying to find the code where the product is added to a category but I haven't had much luck. I believe it should be in module-visual-merchandiser. Currently, when a product gets added to a category, it automatically goes to the end of the category but I want the product to have position 0 by default. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: if you are asking about the position in which it is displayed on frontend, products will be sorted based on the selected sort by option

Comment: @Piyush No. I'm talking about Magento admin. When you add a product to a category, it gets assigned the last position by default and yes, you could manually move it to the top to update the position but they're asking for it to be at position 0 by default. Does that make sense?